# How to modify existing tables for timezone addition

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-design, architecture, timezone

I have a large application with 500+ tables, I have to convert the application to be timezone aware (currently application uses `new java.util.Date()`, `GETDATE()` with server's timezone). i.e. no timezone support whatsoever.

I have organised this task into a few steps so as to ease development, my first identified step is to change all old dates to `UTC` based on the server's timezone. (mostly located in one timezone, so this is my best guess)

Next, I need to modify the database and application code to save all dates in UTC with a timezone name and offset, this is where my problem comes in...

How would i go about modifying the database/tables to support this in a good manner?

My ideas were to:

1. for each date/time column in a table, add two extra columns (for tz-name & offset)

   - this feels like bad design
2. add one table with columns `pk`, `TABLE_NAME`, `COL_NAME`, `ROW_PK`, `TZ_NAME`, `TZ_OFFSET`

   - although more portable, this table will contain millions of rows evetually, since it is the whole database's dates crammed into one table
3. add a new table for each existing table (one-to-one) with tz-names, and offsets for each date column

   - although not portable, this seems like the best (relational) option

Does anyone have any other ideas or best-practices?

Comment: Why do you want to store the timezone in the database. I'd expect the backend to use only one timezone, namely UTC and do the conversion on the frontend when necessary, but not store it.

Comment: Basically to get the timezone that the data was saved in, i can't assume the user won't change timezone, and I need an accurate historical time for each record in the database

Comment: I suggest to: If the users add date/time information, convert the users local timezone to UTC and save UTC in the database. If the GUI displays a value to the user, convert it to their local time during display.

Comment: Thank you, i understand that perfectly, my question was how to structure my existing database to save timezone names with the current data

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a `datetimeoffset` or `timestamp with timezone` type - neither of which are supported by mysql.  You will probably have to store multiple columns.

Comment: @MattJohnson, exactly, i thought about that as well, but since I have to support mysql as well it creates a problem, so my question was actually about the architecture of how to support it generically, between one of those 3 options, or something new I have not thought of :)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you should generally store the data as UTC, with the relevant timezone in a separate column. Having a table for timezones and storing the timezone key is the reasonable thing to do with a relational database.

In this case though, all your data is in a local time already, so in this case you can store the local time in the time column, and add a column for the time zone. That way you don't have to convert the dates that are already in the database.

Storing offset is not necessary, unless you end up noticing that converting from date and zone to offset is too time-consuming.